My Django for-loop is not displaying the elements
I'm making a loop to display all the songs in my music streaming website homepage with a carousel but is not working (it doesn't display nothing but i have like 10 songs in my database). How can i fix it?
This is my html code:
<div id="All-songs" style="padding: 5px">
    <h2>All Songs</h2>
    <div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{"groupCells":5 , "contain": true, "pageDots": false, "draggable": false, "cellAlign": "left", "lazyLoad": true}'>
        {% for i in allsongs %}
            <div class="carousel-cell">
                <section class="main_song">
                    <div class="song-card">
                        <div class="containera">
                            <img src="{{i.image}}" id="A_{{i.id}}" alt="song cover">
                            <div class="overlaya"></div>
                            <div>
                                <a class="play-btn" href="{{i.preview_url}}" id="{{i.id}}"><i> class="fas fa-play-circle"></i></a>
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                    <div class="add-playlist-btn">
                                        <a id="W_{{i.song_id}}" title="Add to Playlist" onclick="showDiv(this)"></a>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p class="songName" id="B_{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <p class="artistName">{{i.singer1}}</p>
                </section>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

this is views.py:
def allSongs(request):
allsongs = list(Song.objects.all())
random.shuffle(allsongs)
return render(request, 'allSongs.html', {'allsongs': allsongs)

and this is models.py:
class Song(models.Model):
song_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
artist = models.CharField(max_length=50)
album = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
genre = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default='Album')
song = models.FileField(upload_to="media/songs/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['mp3', 'wav'])], default="name")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/songimage/", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png'])], default="https://placehold.co/300x300/png")
data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']


On the first look, I don't see why it wouldn't show. Can you please check if allsongs is populated with what you want? Also, you can add check if allsongs has elements and see if there is a problem. Also, your i tag is not correctly written: <i> class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>.

In your views.py you can use print to see what your allsongs variable is containing. You can use if block to see what you are getting in template. Like this: {% if allsongs %}     <p>Found {{ allsongs|length }} songs.</p> {% else %}     <p>No songs found.</p> {% endif %}

ok it display "No songs found". i was making an error

Then I guess you don't have songs in database.

yes i have 12 songs...

if it doesn't show songs then maybe something wrong with your database. Maybe you add songs to different database. What database do you use? If SQLite then it could create file in different folder and you check wrong file. But first you could use print() to check what you get with Song.objects.all()

I solved the problem integrating the allSongs view(in the app views.py) to the homepage view(in the project views.py) like this:
def homepage(request):
     songs = Song.objects.all()
     return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'songs': songs})

